# How I can write a backslash in C# when i receibe a double backslash?

Tags: c#

this is my code:

```
 public string[] Leer_Config_BD(string servidor, string bd, string usuario, string password,string ruta, int primeraCarga)
        {
            string[] info = new string[5];

            if (primeraCarga == 0)
            {

                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ruta))
                {
                    string ln;

                    while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (ln.StartsWith("Servidor"))
                        {
                            servidor = (string)Convert.ToString(ln.Split("=")[1]);
                            info[0] = servidor.Replace(" ", "");
                            info[0] = ReplaceFirst(info[0], "\\", "\\");
                        }

                   }  
               }       
        }

public string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
        string result = "";
        if(pos < 0)
        {
            return text;
        }
        else
        {
                result = text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + 
search.Length);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

When i call the function like this:

```
ReplaceFirst(info[0], "\\", "\\");
```

When the code do all the function i receive from ReplaceFirst a path with double backslash and i need only 1 backslash where's my error? I tried changed with "\" or "@\"

Example of the debugger when returns the string
[image: Example of the debugger when returns the string]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247720/discussion-on-question-by-jeech-how-i-can-write-a-backslash-in-c-when-i-receibe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is an escape character in C#. This means the string `"\\"` really is just `"\"` so if you want to look for double backlash you will want to use `"\\\\"`. (see [ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32060.c-escape-characters.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20escape%20characters%20are%20represented%20in,Literal%20question%20mark%20%207%20more%20rows%20))

Check this example out

```cs
var orig = "Hey\\\\a"; // Hey\\a

Console.WriteLine(orig);

// Take note of the single quote here for char typed param instead of double quotes
var result = Replace(orig, @"\\", '\\'); 

Console.WriteLine(result); // Hey\a
```